# Could not find method include() for arguments [:app] on root project Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

I am trying to import an android project to Android studio,after importing and then clicking on the green run button :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- Where:

> Build file
>   '/home/myusername/prjcts/nomadx/settings.gradle' line: 1

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'nomadx'.

> Could not find method include() for arguments [:app] on root project 'nomadx'.

The content of the file `settings.gradle`

```
include ':app'
```

Comment: would help to show -at least- the contents of your settings.gradle file

Comment: I assumed the ":" in the beginning of your import was the reason & would suggest to remove it (include 'app'). However, it does work on my machine (gradle 2.1 on my machine) with the ":". Using plain gradle though, not using Android studio

Comment: Ops, the gradle shows me on the console : build Successful . but when Importing the project into the Android studio it shows me the same problem :

Comment: OK, it's an android studio issue then. Sorry, cannot help on this one...

Comment: is it a bug ? or what !!

Comment: It certainly looks like a bug, but I guess it's not gradle to blame. Maybe post a message on ADT (..) forum (or add 'android- studio' tag on this post)

Comment: Did you try removing the ":" ? as in "include 'app'"

Comment: Yead I did that,same issue !

Comment: In that case: cannot help on this one..

Comment: The issue still exists in android studio 4.1.3. I create a new application from the wizard, but it can not run and pop the issue. So does this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem ; for those who have the same issue : You should build the `gradle` with the Terminal/console not with Android studio :

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: @shriduttkothari updating your AS should solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

After getting this error on first setup:
[capacitor.settings.gradle' as it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267827/capacitor-settings-gradle-as-it-does-not-exist)

..I used two commands from that page: `npx cap sync android` and `npm install --save @capacitor/core @capacitor/cli`. I'm not sure which one fixed that error, but it gave me the one on this page. I didnt want to build Gradle again when Android Studio should have it, so I restarted it and it started downloading a bunch of Gradle stuff to: /home/user/.gradle. It then prompted me to upgrade Gradle.

I then got a similar error to the OP `Could not find method include() for arguments [:app] on root project 'android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`.

So finally running the above `./gradlew assembleRelease`, this error was shown:
`To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager. All licenses can be accepted using the sdkmanager command line tool: sdkmanager.bat --licenses`

I installed SDK `sudo snap install android-sdk` but didnt have it. Installed with `sudo apt install sdkmanager` and then `sudo sdkmanager --licences` (y) to accept.. and got the same error. Found sdkmanager under Tools in AStudio. Tried to update there, but failed. Opened with `sudo android-studio`, had to select `/home/user/.config/Google/AndroidStudioX.Y`