# Trying to include Gradle project as dependency, but include() not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies

I have a Gradle project which depends on another Gradle project. My project structure is like this:

- project1

  - build.gradle
  - settings.gradle
  - src/
- project2

  - build.gradle
  - settings.gradle
  - src/

in `project1/build.gradle` I want to add `project2` as a dependency:

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = [ 'src' ]
        }
    }
}

include ':project2'
project(':project2').projectDir = new File("../project2")

dependencies {
    compile project(':project2')
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm always getting this error message:

> Error:(21, 0) Could not find method include() for arguments [:project2] on root project 'project1' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

I'm using Gradle 3.5 and I'm getting this error both on the command line (`gradle build`) and in IntelliJ. I found a few StackOverflow threads about the same issue ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886259/could-not-find-method-include-for-arguments-app-on-root-project-android-stu) and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544093/could-not-find-method-include-for-arguments-app-on-root-project-myproject)), but they were not helpful.

The [Gradle multi-project documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) also doesn't mention any specific requirements which I may be missing that can cause the error.

When I leave the `include` call out, I get the message that the project path could not be found in the root project.

I also tried moving the dependency to a subdirectory of `project1`, but without success.

I wonder what I'm doing wrong and why apparently not many other people are having the same problem. I'd be grateful for hints.

Note: this is not an Android project.

Comment: `include` should be invoked in a separate file named: `settings.gradle` - please give it a try.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose that was what I was missing. However, now I'm getting the message that the read-only property projectDir cannot be set. I worked around it by specifying compile project(':..:project2') as the dependency and removing the projectDir assigment.

Comment: You can't do that with gradle. Either both projects must be sub-projects of a multi-project build (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html), or you must use a composite build (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As pointed out in the first comment, `include` actually needs to go into `settings.gradle` and not into `build.gradle`. The same applies to changing the `projectDir` property.

Comment 3 gave also me another idea. The project can be included in `settings.gradle` as follows:

```
includeBuild '../project2'
```

and in `project1/build.gradle` I specify the dependency as

```
dependencies {
    compile 'group:project2:version'
}
```

I generally like this better, since it's less code and looks cleaner. The downside, however, is that recursive composite builds aren't possible. So if `project2` itself is also a composite build, this won't work.

Comment: Adding to @Janek's solution, if you don't have group and version then simply add compile ':project2:'