# capacitor.settings.gradle' as it does not exist

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, nuxt.js, capacitor

I am new to Ionic while build the app in android. Its opening a project in Android Studio but while gradle sync its showing the following error

```
Could not read script 'F:\IonicProjects\mis-tracking-master-latest\mis-tracking-master\mis-tracking\android\capacitor.settings.gradle' as it does not exist.
```

Answer (score 118):

Try to sync your Ionic project by command:

```
ionic capacitor sync android
```

Answer (score 30):

**JUST DO**

```
npx cap sync android
```

> If you only use capacitor from (Vuejs, nuxtjs, etc.)

Answer (score 12):

Same thing happen to me. I did a

> npm install --save @capacitor/core @capacitor/cli

and this fixes it.

Comment: This fixed it for me had to rerun `ionic capacitor add android` and it worked after

Comment: this fixed my issue. thanks, man.

Answer (score 3):

change the name of my file /android/settings.gradle to capacitor.settings.grandle works for me

Answer (score 2):

just do

```
npm install jetifier
npx jetify
npx cap sync android
```

[image]

Capacitor troubleshooting
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android/troubleshooting

Comment: This worked for me on android BumbleBee. Only the cap command was required

Answer (score 2):

This is what solved it for me:
I'm using next/JS and I export it. So the build folder is not "build", it is "out".

Just go to the capacitor.config.json and change the webDir property to out

Answer (score 2):

run `ionic build` before you run `npx cap add android`

Answer (score 1):

1. Over folder project execute: $ capacitor update android
2. On Android Studio execute: File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: Thanks! This answer solved the sync problem with my vue + ionic 6 application in Android Studio 2020.3.1

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me was:
`npm run build`